# Android background thread communication

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

I would like to create two threads (T1 and T2) from main thread that can communicate with each other. I am looking at the best way to accomplish this. 
My idea is to do this with the handler. Is this OK?
The problem is that I do not know how can T1 obtain a handler reference for T2 and vice versa.

EDIT.

Let me explain situation in more detail. If some condition happens in T1 I want signal that to T2 so that T2 can do some other work.

Comment: if they are blood related (parent child relationship) it shouldn't really be a problem,  if not you need to provide a common place where they can register themselves thus enabling communication between them

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public class Test {

    static abstract class MyThread extends Thread implements Callback{
        Callback mCallback;
        public void setCallBack(Callback pCallBack){
            mCallback = pCallBack;
        }

    }

    static interface Callback{
        public void onAction(Object... args);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyThread T1 = new MyThread(){

            @Override
            public void onAction(Object... args) {
                //code when onAction is called.

            }

            public void run(){
                //T1 thread code here

                //if some condition
                //call the Callback
                mCallback.onAction();
            }

        };

        MyThread T2 = new MyThread(){
            @Override
            public void onAction(Object... args) {
                //code when onAction is called.
                //"Other work"
            }

            public void run(){
                //T2 thread code here

            }

        };

        T1.setCallBack(T2);
        T2.setCallBack(T1);

        T1.start();
        T2.start();
    }
}
```